# Accurate explanation of diode reverse bias mechanism

Tags: diodes, semiconductors, electrostatic

For quite some time I haven't been able to convince myself how reverse bias works using conventional explanations that involve words like 'minority carriers', 'majority carriers' etc. which do not make much sense to me.

Consider the image below: [image]
Now I am an electron in that depletion region. I was not here initially, I was in the wire (free-moving electron of a copper atom) or perhaps battery (...of an ion?) but now I have been pushed here.

I feel attracted to the positive charges (which are for example phosphorous atoms with four valence electrons, hence the + charge) at the same time I also feel the repulsion from the negative terminal of the battery. I feel tempted (as well as all my electron friends) to move across the border and happily combine with the phosphorous ions, which is not happening. So what stops me there??

I am actually expecting to see answers that require knowledge about solid state physics particularly band gap and band theory, fermi-dirac stats etc., which I do not know enough about and need to get a lot more reading. Can anyone please confirm this so I can move on feeling a little more assured and come back to this after I know enough about solid state physics.

UPDATE: from [the same question on physics stack exchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/396030/please-grant-me-an-accurate-explanation-of-diode-reverse-bias-mechanism/396073?noredirect=1#comment888394_396073)
It could be probably due to that, somehow, my friends and I are bound to those impurity trivalent ions i.e. we are immobile in this context. But somehow forward biasing makes us mobile again.

Comment: I think you are forgetting about the diffusion currents, Feynamn's explaination is OK.  Read 14-4 14-5, 
 http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/III_14.html

Comment: It seems helpful at first sight, I will read it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your premise is flawed:

> Now I am an electron in that depletion region. I was not here initially, I was in the wire (free-moving electron of a copper atom) or perhaps battery (...of an ion?) but now I have been pushed here.

If you started elsewhere, you have definitely NOT been pushed into the depletion region. If anything, you were pushed AWAY from ever entering it because of the strong electric field that exists there.

In terms of your diagram, electrons from the battery enter the diode from the left. The first thing they encounter is is all the negative ions on the left side of the depletion region, which repels the free electrons.

Comment: Ahh, what I mean is that when the diode is in thermal equilibrium and not biased, I was elsewhere outside the diode. Only when the battery is connected, electrons are pushed to the depleted region OR you can say holes are pulled to the positive terminal of the battery (is it ok to assume hole as simply absence of e-?) causing the depleted region to widen. Only when the whole thing reaches equilibrium i.e. the voltage of the battery equals the voltage of the diode(or treated as a capacitor), that electrons are blocked out from getting near. I am among the first batches and not the late comers.

Comment: It doesn't matter. Even with no external bias, the diode has a depletion region, which is produced because it reduces the total energy of the device to have electrons from the N-side donors "drop into" the holes in the nearby P-side acceptors. This creates the initial electric field. Adding more reverse bias from the battery merely accentuates this effect.

Comment: Saying this, why doesn't adding reverse bias pushes the electrons that, under no bias, moved into the holes to form depletion region back to n-region? (instead of accentuating the effect)

Comment: No, that's what happens under *forward* bias, when the external E-field opposes the internal field and eventually cancels it out (at approximately 0.65V for silicon). Under reverse bias, the external voltage causes more electrons to shift sides, with the resulting E-field simply adding to the internal field and increasing the width of the depletion region.

Comment: You're partially right? Under reverse bias, with the external E-field adding to that internal field, the electrons can't simply shift sides which in the process requires them to travel/diffuse from N to P region, which is going against both the internal and external E-field as both of them want to move electrons from P to N (reverse current). I think it is more appropriate to say that the external E-field puts electrons into P- and pulls electrons out of N-region. Like instead of turning back from living room to kitchen, you go outside, turn to backyard and enter the kitchen from backdoor.

Comment: Yes, on further consideration, I realized that my wording could be confusing, so I fixed it.